# In Java, how to reload dynamically resources bundles in a web application?

Tags: java, resources, resourcebundle

We are using fmt:setBundle to load a resource bundle from a database (we extended the ResourceBundle class to do that).
When we modify a value in database, we have to reload the web server to display the new value on the web app.

Is there any simple way to use the new value without restarting the web server ?

(We do **not** want to always look up the value from database but we would like to invalidate the cache, for example by calling a special 'admin' URL)

EDIT : We are using JDK 1.4, so I would prefer a solution on that version. :)

Comment: If you're not too attached to the ResourceBundle class itself, then Spring's MessageSource abstraction provides a more flexible approach, including caching and reloading messages.  It can wrap your custom ResourceBundle. You can just use that bit of the Spring API on its own, if necessary.

Comment: The answer is probably specific to the Servlet contain (app server) you are using, e.g. Tomcat or JBoss. Which one?

Comment: We're using Tomcat to develop but Websphere Application Server for production (5.X).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you might want to look into Spring - particularly the [ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html).

Answer (score 7):

If you're using JDK 1.6 you can use the callback methods `getTimeToLive()` and `needsReload()` in [ResourceBundle.Control](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.Control.html) to control if the bundle cache needs to be loaded with new values from the database.

Answer (score 1):

First you can create a class which extends from `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` to expose its inner class protected method called `getProperties`. This method return a concurrent map from `PropertiesHolder` object. Second you should configure a bean of that extended class in you web configuration class. Now you able to use messageSource in your service or business layer. Here is the reference link [Configure reloadable message source bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55914458/5874302)

Comment: You should provide at least some part of the lin as an explanation in your answer

Comment: Kindly just click on the given link, I hope will get enough explanation.

Comment: @ilkerkaran i edit my answer and add a brief explanation.