# MessageSource doesn't reload properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

There is a messageSource Bean:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource(){
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource=new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/messages/messages");
    return messageSource;
}
```

I have read somewhere that If I use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` messageSource shouldn't be cached and everytime look into the properties file if theere is particular string. Sadly with bean created that way It doesn't work. After compiling If I add some properties Spring Boot won't find it.
Properties file is in `/resources/messages/messages.properties` and /resources`/messages/messages_en.properties` .

Comment: Try to set the `cacheSeconds`using `setCacheSeconds` to 0?

Comment: Another thing as mentioned in the javadocs: 
"With a "classpath:" prefix, resources can still be loaded from the classpath, but "cacheSeconds" values other than "-1" (caching forever) might not work reliably in this case."
So if `cacheSeconds` doesn't work try to place the message files outside of classpath and use the absolute path in the `setBaseNames`

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla adding `setCacheMillis(0)` didn't help. About path, if my messages are in resources folder shouldn't it be enough? Since it's in resources folder it should me put "/messages/messages.properties", isn't it? Do you have any idea how to make it work in intelij (maybe its intelij fault) ?

Comment: You should be able to give an absolute path something like /opt/resources/message try it with that.

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla sadly none of those below didn't work: `app/src/main/resources/messages/messages`, `/src/main/resources/messages/messages`, `main/resources/messages/messages`, `resources/messages/messages`, `messages/messages` .

Comment: Please share the code or if possible a small working app.

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla I found out that when I use `ResourceBundleMessageSource` Spring is able to load my files from basename set to `messages/messages` (but won't reload it after loading it), but when I use `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` Sprig doesn't load properties file... At this point, I have no idea what could be wrong. It isn't that much of small app. Can I give you github link?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158344/discussion-between-mohamedsanaulla-and-ogarogar).

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla Ok so I solved my issue... I put my messages folder into webapp folder (next to WEB-INF folder) and change basename to: `/messages/messages` and now everything works just fine...  Sadly I have no freakin idea why it started working just fine (because ResourceBundleMessageSource worked with /resources/messages/message). Anyways thank you for your time and If you know why it started working that way I would be more than happy to read your explanation. Have a nice day/night !

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.
First: configure the bean in your web configuration as shown below.

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource () {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSourceExt messageResource =
            new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSourceExt();
    messageResource.setAlwaysUseMessageFormat(false);
    messageResource.setBasenames("classpath:messages");
    messageResource.setDefaultEncoding(CHARACTER_ENCODING);
    messageResource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(true);
    messageResource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
    messageResource.setCacheSeconds(1); // by default it set to -1 which means cache 
                                        // forever messageSourse.
                                        // set 0 to check reload messeageSource on 
                                        // every getMessageSource request but reload 
                                        // only those files which last modified 
                                        // timestamp is changed.
                                        // value greater than 1 is treated as the 
                                        // time interval between reload.
    return messageResource;
}
```

Second: create a class which extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource to expose the protected method of its inner class as shown below.

```
public class ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSourceExt extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {

public Properties getPropertiesByFileName(String fileName){
    return super.getProperties(fileName).getProperties();
}
```

}

Third: Now Autowired the bean like this.

```
@Service 
public class MyMessagesBundleService {

final private String fileName = "classpath:messages";

@Autowired
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSourceExt messageSource;
Properties properties = messageSource.getPropertiesByFileName(this.fileName);
// now change the properties and saved it.
// after saved call clear cache and get again.
messageSource.clearCache();

}
```